# Returning the query or the result in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

What are the pros and cons of fetching the database and returning the query object or the result/result_array?

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
return $query;
```

vs

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
return $query->result; //or result_array()
```

I know that if you return the query object, it makes it flexible for the developer to fetch whatever type of resource she wants. But this could lead to more ambiguity in code design.

What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you need to do with it, process it further or show it to the user. If simple the results have to be shown in the View, I'd rather return the result otherwise if more "complex" processing is needed you could return the query-object.

Answer (score 1):

You should return result object or array because later you can modify it and have more data in it without changing the function behavior.

Let me pick up an example :

getTopic($id) suppose this function returns all the topics based on courseware id for some Coursewares.  Later you might want to have the count also of the respective topics. In the cases wherein you return result object or array its easier to do ; just add one more index.

Also, if you just want to have the query object, call it straight from the controller whats the need for routing it through a function. Function call means you want processed data (now or later) not a direct output from a query.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to pass the query object because it can be passed directly to `$this->table->generate($query)` and it will include the column headers whereas if you pass the `result()` or `result_array()` you lose the headers.